# File Scope? Swift Delegates and Protocols

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm working on building a new Swift app roughly based off an old Obj-c app. I'm currently working on the delegates

Here is what my obj-c code looked like in the .h file

```
@interface MyAppViewController : CustomViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyAppViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol MyAppViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myAppViewController:(MyAppViewController *)controller loggedInStudent:    (MYStudent *)student;
- (void)myAppViewControllerWantsSignUp:(MyAppViewController *)controller;
@end
```

In SWIFT I did:

```
class MyAppViewController: CustomViewController {

var delegate: MyAppViewControllerDelegate?
protocol MyAppViewControllerDelegate{
func myAppViewController(controller: MyAppViewController, loggedInStudent:     MYStudent)
func myAppViewControllerWantsSignUp(controller: MyAppViewController)
```

I've done a lot of reading and study on this, so I thought I was doing it basically right (totally new to swift though... so)

I'm getting this error though, "`Declaration is only valid in file scope`" on the `protocol MyAppViewControllerDelegate {`
I assumed this had something to do with declaring it within the class, so I moved it out, only now my code within the class doesn't recognize the delegate variable I declared..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be this:

```
protocol MyAppViewControllerDelegate {
    func myAppViewController(controller: MyAppViewController, loggedInStudent:     MYStudent)
    func myAppViewControllerWantsSignUp(controller: MyAppViewController)
}

class MyAppViewController: CustomViewController {

    var delegate: MyAppViewControllerDelegate?
}
```

Although, if you're following a common pattern where the object that owns `MyAppViewController` is also its delegate, this may cause memory issues.  You can use `class` typing to allow weak delegation like so:

```
protocol MyAppViewControllerDelegate : class {
    func myAppViewController(controller: MyAppViewController, loggedInStudent:     MYStudent)
    func myAppViewControllerWantsSignUp(controller: MyAppViewController)
}

class MyAppViewController: CustomViewController {

    weak var delegate: MyAppViewControllerDelegate?
}
```

This is slightly limiting because it requires you to use a class for your delegate, but it will help avoid retain cycles :)

Answer (score 2):

From what I see in your source code is that you've declared your protocol inside of your class.
Just declare the protocol outside of the class declaration and you'll be fine.

**Update:**

The default access level is set to internal which is defined as

> Internal access enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, >but not in any source file outside of that module. You typically use internal access when >defining an app’s or a framework’s internal structure.

In contrast to Objective-C or C you don't need a forward declaration if the implementation haven't happened before the usage.

Source: [The Swift Programming Language, Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)